# OpenCV OSX Mavericks video codec issue

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg, osx-mavericks

Firstly, I've installed ffmpeg using

```
sudo port install ffmpeg
```

on my Macbook OSX 10.9 and XCode 5.1. I've done the same for OpenCV

```
sudo port install opencv
```

and I got face detect working using this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19712385/849791). However, when trying to open a video file in the source code folder using VideoCapture I get the error "WARNING: Couldn't read movie file Alireza_Day1_001.avi". Has anyone faced the same issue? (FYI VideoCapture from my webcam is working fine, but tried opening a .mov and .avi file without luck) Any help is much appreciated!