# Python bindings for opencv

Tags: python, macos, opencv, homebrew

I've managed to install opencv using [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22496727/205832). However, unlike posts like [this](http://jjyap.wordpress.com/2014/05/24/installing-opencv-2-4-9-on-mac-osx-with-python-support/) and [this](https://gist.github.com/robb-broome/9222746) I don't get any python bindings. Nothing python related.

```
$ cd /opt/boxen/homebrew/Cellar/opencv/2.4.9
$ find . | grep py
```

Nothing! :(
I don't mind doing some hacks on the PYTHONPATH and whatnot but there are no files my python can try to import.

Comment: Can you share the link you get from `brew gist-logs opencv`?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/2077c6b14139f551cd37

Answer (score 0):

Mayber you could just do this? Replacing . to *?

```
find * | grep py
```

Else, you can search by yourself to opencv/2.4.9/build/python/* ?

Are you sure you didn't downloaded the source only?

Comment: There are no py files.

Comment: I didn't download anything. I use brew install.

Comment: On linux, you do not directly download the binairies, you have to recompile OR install the package python-opencv

Comment: homebrew is only available for OSX.